# How do i connect Rest Api to Springboot frontend using thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, spring-mvc, frontend

So i have 3 Entity classes : BloodBank, BloodStock, Seeker
i have 3 rest controllers,  3 Service Interfaces + 3 Implementation classes for them
i have tested the api in Postman, it works!
i've created another package where i have the controller for the frontend and i have an html file called seeker.html in the templates folder where i'm trying to display the data in a table but its not working.

I'm getting this error:
Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

html page:

```
<!--!-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Seeker Information</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Seeker Information</h1>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>First Name</th>
                <th>Last Name</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Gender</th>
                <th>Blood Group</th>
                <th>City</th>
                <th>Phone Number</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <!-- Iterate over the seekers and display their information -->
            <tr th:each="seeker : ${seekers}">
                <td th:text="${seeker.id}"></td>
                <td th:text="${seeker.firstName}"></td>
                <td th:text="${seeker.lastName}"></td>
                <td th:text="${seeker.age}"></td>
                <td th:text="${seeker.gender}"></td>
                <td th:text="${seeker.bloodGroup}"></td>
                <td th:text="${seeker.city}"></td>
                <td th:text="${seeker.phone}"></td>
                
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>


FrontEnd Controller

@Controller
public class SeekerController {
    private final SeekerService seekerService;

    public SeekerController(SeekerService seekerService) {
        this.seekerService = seekerService;
    }

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String showAllSeekers(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("seekers", seekerService.findAllSeeker());
        return "seeker"; // Return the name of the HTML template
    }
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.